# How to compute conditional expected value $E(Y|X-Y)$

Tags: probability

Is there any property that could help me out on how to compute $E(Y|X-Y)$, given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: By compute, do you mean using $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ or similar?

Comment: Yes. I also know $f_{Y|X}, f_Y, f_X, f_{XY}$. My problem is $f_{Y|X-Y}$.

Comment: @Daniel you might write $E(Y\mid X-Y=z)$, Is $X,Y$ are i.i.d. or only independent?

Comment: $f_{XY} = (\lambda_x e^{-\lambda_xx}) (\lambda_y e^{-\lambda_yy})$. The density/distribution parameters are different.

Comment: Your comment about $f_{XY}$ should be a part of question.

Comment: Indeed, the comments should.

Comment: Do you know how to find the joint density of $Y$ and $X-Y$? This is a good starting point :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes. I also know $f_{Y|X},f_Y,f_X,f_{X,Y}$. My problem is $f_{Y|X−Y}$.

$$f_{Y\mid X-Y}(y\mid z) ~{=~ \dfrac{f_{X-Y,Y}(z,y)}{f_{X-Y}(z)} \\=~ \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(z+y, y)}{{\small\displaystyle\int}_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}( z+t, t)\mathrm d t}}$$

Thus:

$$\mathsf E(Y\mid X-Y) ~{=~ \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R t\;f_{X-Y,Y}(X-Y, t)\;\mathrm d t}{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R f_{X-Y,Y}(X-Y,t)\;\mathrm d t} \\=~ \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R t\;f_{X,Y}(X-Y+t,t)\;\mathrm d t}{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(X-Y+t,t)\;\mathrm d t}}$$

> $f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)~=~λ_{\small X}e^{−λ_{\small X}x}\cdot λ_{\small Y}e^{−λ_{\small Y}y}$

*Presumably* this supported over $\{(x,y): x>0, y>0\}$ ...?

$$\mathsf E(Y\mid X-Y) ~{=~ \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R t\;e^{(-\lambda_{\small_X}(X-Y)-(\lambda_{\small X}+\lambda_{\small Y})t)}\;\mathbf 1_{X-Y+t\geqslant 0 ~\cap~ t\geqslant 0}\;\mathrm d t}{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R e^{(-\lambda_{\small_X}(X-Y)-(\lambda_{\small X}+\lambda_{\small Y})}t)\;\mathbf 1_{X-Y+t\geqslant 0~\cap~ t\geqslant 0}\;\mathrm d t} \\ \phantom{= ~\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{\max\{Y-X,0\}}^\infty t\;e^{-(\lambda_{\small X}+\lambda_{\small Y})t}\;\mathrm d t}{\displaystyle\int_{\max\{Y-X,0\}}^\infty e^{-(\lambda_{\small X}+\lambda_{\small Y})t}\;\mathrm d t} \\ =~ \max\{Y-X,0\}+(\lambda_{\small X}+\lambda_{\small Y})^{-1} }}$$

Comment: Yes,  $x,y \in [0,+\infty)$. I haven't understood $f_{X-Y, Y}(z,y) = f_{X,Y}(z+y, y)$. Is it $Z = X - Y \implies X = Z +Y$?

Comment: Yes, @Daniel .  It is linear change of variables.